# OpenCV - testing accuracy of classifier?

Tags: java, opencv, classification

I have created several programs incorporating OpenCV and have trained my own classifier.

How would I be able to find the accuracy of these classifiers?  In the form of a percentage?

I understand what makes these programs more or less accurate but I'm unsure of how I would be able to test how accurate it is.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: You want to test the accuracy of a (machine learning) classifier? Is it possible to provide some context?

Answer (score 1):

There are two plots that are commonly used for this purpose.
[Precision-Recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) and [Receiver Operating Characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic).

These plots are normally used for two-class (true/false) evaluation.
Is your problem multi-class? If so, [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51296/how-to-calculate-precision-and-recall-for-multiclass-classification-using-confus) might help.